# Which information from facebook login should I store in the database?

Tags: facebook, email, authentication, token, facebook-login

I have an user table with email and password fields. When I implement Facebook Login, the callback url sent me three informations:
- User ID
- User email
- User access token

I want to know should I use user's email as the email and user's access token as the password. Is the token permanent?
If not, so what should I use as a password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to store the User ID in order to identify returning users. Email might be pointless, because it is not required for using Facebook. Access Tokens are not valid forever, you should not store them. There is no password to store either, that is not how it works. For re-login, the user authorizes through Facebook, NOT through your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user email as email but do not use user's access token as the password because it is NOT permanent.